# Accounting for waves when doing planar reflections

Tags: mathematics, directx, hlsl, reflection-rendering

I've been studying Nvidia's examples from the SDK, in particular the [Island11](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-graphics-sdk-11-direct3d) project and I've found something curious about a piece of HLSL code which corrects the reflections up and down depending on the state of the wave's height.

Naturally, after examining the brief paragraph of code:

```
// calculating correction that shifts reflection up/down according to water wave Y position
float4 projected_waveheight = mul(float4(input.positionWS.x,input.positionWS.y,input.positionWS.z,1),g_ModelViewProjectionMatrix);
float waveheight_correction=-0.5*projected_waveheight.y/projected_waveheight.w;
projected_waveheight = mul(float4(input.positionWS.x,-0.8,input.positionWS.z,1),g_ModelViewProjectionMatrix);
waveheight_correction+=0.5*projected_waveheight.y/projected_waveheight.w;
reflection_disturbance.y=max(-0.15,waveheight_correction+reflection_disturbance.y);
```

My first guess was that it compensates for the planar reflection when it is subjected to vertical perturbation (the waves), shifting the reflected geometry to a point where is nothing and the water is just rendered as if there is nothing there or just the sky:

[image]

Now, that's the sky reflecting where we should see the terrain's green/grey/yellowish reflection lerped with the water's baseline. My problem is now that I cannot really pinpoint what is the logic behind it. Projecting the actual world space position of a point of the wave/water geometry and then multiplying by -.5f, only to take another projection of the same point, this time with its y coordinate changed to -0.8 (why -0.8?).

Clues in the code seem to indicate it was derived with trial and error because there is redundancy. For example, the author takes the negative half of the projected y coordinate (after the w divide):

```
float waveheight_correction=-0.5*projected_waveheight.y/projected_waveheight.w;
```

And then does  the same for the second point (only positive, to get a difference of some sort, I presume) and combines them:

```
waveheight_correction+=0.5*projected_waveheight.y/projected_waveheight.w;
```

By removing the divide by 2, I see no difference in quality improvement (if someone cares to correct me, please do). **The crux of it seems to be the difference in the projected y, why is that?** This redundancy and the seemingly arbitrary selection of -.8f and -0.15f lead me to conclude that this might be a combination of heuristics/guess work. **Is there a logical underpinning to this or is it just a desperate hack?**

Here is an exaggeration of the initial problem which the code fragment fixes, observe on the lowest tessellation level. Hopefully, it might spark an idea I'm missing. The -.8f might be a reference height from which to deduce how much to disturb the texture coordinate sampling the planarly reflected geometry render and -.15f might be the lower bound, a security measure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This technique is bound to have this artefact, and that is why most of the time when it is used, we apply a vertical shift into the lookup to do like if the actual reflection plane was half a meter above its real position. Yes it has the drawback of not having a perfectly matching reflection, but it is preferable to holes.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?